# svn client from DOS BAT file prompting for password

Tags: svn, dos

I'm using Sliksvn Windows client and have a DOS BAT file that contains the svn command below to list contents of a repository.

```
svn --username raj --password N:7Rt%2+ --non-interactive list -v svn://dev.somehost.com/project1/data/dropbox
```

I get the error

> svn: Authentication error from server: Password incorrect

When I type the same command directly in a DOS window it works so I'm sure the password is correct. I suspect that the characters in the passowrd are reserved characters or something like so is there a way to pass the password without the DOS command trying to interpret the characters. I already tried putting the password around double quotes, single quotes and putting = after --password. 
Can someone suggest a solution to this as I cannot ask for the password to be changed.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In batch files, the '%' symbol marks environment variables. Use %% (two of them) so it gets translated a percent mark:

```
--password N:7Rt%%2+
```